# How to pass data using ajaxFileUpload jQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-plugins

I am using [ajaxFileUpload](http://www.phpletter.com/our-projects/ajaxfileupload/) jQuery plugin to upload an image to ASP.NET server.

I was able to upload an image successfully, but I also want to pass data to the server as well. I wasn't able to do so. When I try to pass a JSON data I get the following error in the browser's console:

```
jQuery.handleError is not a function
```

The Javascript code:

```
 $.ajaxFileUpload
(
    {
        url: 'http://localhost:23999/administration.asmx/UploadedFile',
        secureuri: false,
        fileElementId: 'ImageUpload',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: "test",
        success: function (data, status) {
            if (typeof (data.error) != 'undefined') {
                if (data.error != '') {
                    alert(data.error);
                } else {
                    alert(data.msg);
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (data, status, e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    }
)
```

WebService C#:

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string UploadedFile()
    {
        var a = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];

        byte[] buffer;
        Stream fileStream = file.InputStream;
        ............
```

How can I pass JSON data to the server? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this link : http://www.jchilders.com/AjaxFileUpload/demo/
it says there's an option you could use to pass data :

> additionalData    : Additional data you would like to pass along with the
>   request.

You can try to send the data this way :

> var data = {      "varId" : varValue };

Comment: It's a different script, and the links to the source don't work

Comment: thanks. Without the "data" option, your code works, right ? Could you show the ajaxfileupload.js code as well please ? can't find it with the link you gave.

Comment: Yes it works without it. When I pass the data value, I can see that it read it inside the plugin, but something goes wrong from that point on, something that I can't figure out.

Comment: It works now with the data for some reason :) -- do you know how can I access it in .NET?

Comment: I need more info to help you. Could you show the plugin code ? And the code you use on the server side ? When you say " I can see that it read it inside the plugin", where exactly do you read it ?

Comment: In the server I get "{0=t&1=e&2=s&3=t} " (I sent the word "test") when querying the HttpContext.Current.Request.Form. Why the string is divided into 4 parameters?